# How to prevent mapbox from reading the currently running service

Tags: android

> The APP explicitly states the collection and usage rules to users in the form of privacy policy pop ups. Without the user's consent, there is a behavior of collecting device MAC address, IMEI, and other information.
> [Test Action] Initiate privacy compliance detection
> Read the current running service
> Pop up privacy policy
> The stack information is as follows:
> At android.app ActivityManager. getRunningServices()
> At com. mapbox. common LifecyclUtils. hasServiceRunningInForeground (LifecyclUtils. kt: 96)
> At com. mapbox. common LifecycleUtils. getLifecycleState (LifecycleUtils. kt: 102)
> At com. mapbox. common LifecycleService.onCreate (LifecycleService. kt: 106)
> At android.app ActivityThread. handleCreatService (ActivityThread. java: 3392)
> At android.app ActivityThread- Wrap4 (Unknown Source: 0)
> At android.app ActivityThread $H.handleMessage (ActivityThread. java: 1730)
> At android.os Handler. dispatchMessage (Handler. java: 106)
> At android.os Looper. loop (Looper. java: 164)
> At android.app ActivityThread. main (ActivityThread. java: 6554)
> At Java. lang. reflect Method. invoke (Native Method)
> At com. android. international. os RuntimeInit $MethodAndArgsCaller. run (RuntimeInit. java: 558)
> At com. android. international. os ZygoteInit. main (ZygoteInit. java: 810)
> How to prevent mapbox from accessing backend running services

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.